# Memcached Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: apache2, memcached, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano3, php-5.6

I am receiving this in my error log each time a page is requested in my web app:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1463227 bytes) in /var/www/releases/20151104184006/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/MemcachedCache.php on line 96
```

I have deployed onto Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, with apache2 and PHP 5.6.14. I am using Capistrano to deploy and set up memcached using capistrano-memcached 1.0. I have the memory set as 512 MB. I have also tried at 1024 MB but it has no effect on the issue.

I have installed https://github.com/lagged/memcache.php to help debug the issue, I have loaded a few pages to trigger the caching and here is the output:

**General Cache Information**

```
PHP Version 5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Memcached Host  1.127.0.0.1:11211
Max Memcache Size   1.1 GBytes
Memcache Server Information
127.0.0.1:11211 Flush server
Memcache Version    Array
Start Time  2015/11/05 10:56:30
Uptime  26 minutes
Memcached Server Version    1.4.14 (Ubuntu)
Used Cache Size 905.8 KBytes
Max Cache Size  1.1 GBytes
Current Connections Count   9
Total Connections So Far    69
Flush CMD count 0
Get CMD count   1393
Set CMD count   390
Items Evicted So Far    0
Bytes Read So Far   964.3 KBytes
Bytes Written So Far    1.9 MBytes
Threads 4
127.0.0.1:11211 Reset stats
Host Status Diagrams
Cache Usage Hits & Misses
Free 1.1 GBytes (99.9%)
Hits 1284 (92.2%)
Used 905.8 KBytes (0.1%)
Misses 109 (7.8%)
```

**Cache Information**

```
Current Items(total)    390 (390)
Hits    1284
Misses  109
Request Rate (hits, misses) 0.89 cache requests/second
Hit Rate    0.82 cache requests/second
Miss Rate   0.07 cache requests/second
Set Rate    0.25 cache requests/second
```

Comment: The error indicates that you only have 128 MB available memory. This is usually sufficient, but I'd check that you are setting you PHP memory settings correctly and restarting Apache. Also, see if you can figure out exactly which code is triggering this. You may have some massive data structure which doesn't need to be so massive.

Comment: The memory in the memcached config is set as 512, where/why does it indicate I only have 128MB available memory? I also have memory_limit set at 512 MB in PHP and have restarted Apache.

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes. (134217728/1024)/1024=128. The error is the php memory limit, not memcached.

Comment: Thanks @will_in_wi that makes sense now that 134217728 bytes = 128 MB  The problem seems to have gone away now. Maybe I hadn't restarted Apache correctly after the php.ini change. Can you add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Answer added. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes. (134217728/1024)/1024 == 128MB. The error is the php memory limit, not memcached.

128 MB is usually sufficient, but I'd check that you are setting your PHP memory settings correctly and restarting Apache. Also, see if you can figure out exactly which code is triggering this. You may have some massive data structure which doesn't need to be so massive.